# Magento 2 configurable product without wizard

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Unless I am missing something I cant seem to associate existing virtual products to a new configurable product. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possible.

Use "Add product Manually" functionality if have to add new variation or click "Select > Choose a different Product" if you need to replace exists

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, however it looks as though your editing a product. I am creating a new configurable product... I have now updated my question with a screenshot